# How to Search a item from a stack?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack

When i'm reading some books, I saw, Time complexity of searching an item from the stack is O(n).But i'm confused with, how can i search a middle value from a stack since it is a LIFO.

Answer (score 5):

A stack is usually implemented as an array or a linked-list, you can iterate though either of those.

**If you have a pure stack API that doesn't provide you with an iterator:**

You have to pop elements on to a different stack until you find the element, then push them back.

After this we'll have the stack back to the way it was.

Answer (score 1):

Because O(n) is linear complexity, so you'd have to pop every element until you found your match. Therefore, the time to search grows in line with the number of elements.

Comment: Yeah, But i need to do that without removing elements.

Comment: You'd have to remove elements. (and then put them back)

Comment: Or make a copy of the stack and work on that (expensive if you have many elements or a lengthy copy constructor)

Answer (score 0):

As very astutely described Duekling / Duncan , may be you would want to create a a stack with a count, and then breaking into two. Let s1 and s2 point to two stacks, so when you push two items in s1, the first node becomes the top of s2 , and the last entered node becomes top of s1. then again two more items are added with the count becoming 4 , push the item3 on s2 and item 4 remains on s1 ..